# Eclipse EMF RAP Target Components

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-rap

Good day all,

I am attempting to get an Eclipse RAP application running with EMF support. Following the steps from the Eclipse wiki (https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/EMF_Integration) as closely as possible (it's dated four years ago), I am putting the following packages into my Target definition:

- EMF RAP Target Components
- RAP Basic Equinox Target
- RAP Runtime

This gives me the following Target definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="SCRAMSTargetDefinition" sequenceNumber="17">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.rap.sdk.feature.group" version="2.13.0.v20170609-0928"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rap.equinox.target.feature.feature.group" version="3.2.0.20170613-1148"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rap.feature.feature.group" version="3.2.0.20170609-1144"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

The Target will not resolve though, giving me the following dependency errors:

```
Problems occurred while resolving the target contents
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
            From: EMF RAP Runtime 2.13.0.v20170609-0928 (org.eclipse.emf.rap.feature.group 2.13.0.v20170609-0928)
            To: org.eclipse.emf.rap.edit.ui.feature.group [2.9.0.v20170609-0928]
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
            From: EMF RAP Target Components  2.13.0.v20170609-0928 (org.eclipse.emf.rap.sdk.feature.group 2.13.v20170609-0928)
            To: org.eclipse.emf.rap.feature.group [2.13.0.v20170609-0928]
        Missing requirement: EMF RAP Edit UI 2.9.0.v20170609-0928 (org.eclipse.emf.rap.edit.ui.feature.group 2.9.0.v20170609-0928) requires 'A.PDE.Target.Platform Cannot be installed into the IDE 0.0.0' but it could not be found
        Software being installed: EMF RAP Target Components 2.13.0.v20170609-0928 (org.eclipse.emf.rap.sdk.feature.group 2.13.0.v20170609-0928)
```

Buried in there is **A.PDE.Target.Platform Cannot be installed into the IDE 0.0.0**, which would seem to be the core problem - but this is a Target Definition, not the IDE itself, so I'm not understanding why it's complaining in this way.

I have tried including combinations of other EMF packages into the Target Definition, but nothing has helped. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [Eclipse Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/42766/):

When adding the update site to the target definition, the *Include required software* option has to be disabled. This is equivalent to switching `includeMode` from `planner` to `slicer`. In addition to that, you might want to enable the *Include all environments* option (set `includeAllPlatforms` to `true`).

Please note that these settings have to be the same for all locations (if the target definition includes more than one location / update site).